# Remove conflicting stuff thunderbird

Tags: uninstall, thunderbird

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and am using Thunderbird for my mail.
The thing is I wasn't getting the notification sound to play,

After Googling and viewing multiple posts, I installed what the guys said I should install, except for I installed way too many different things that I have no clue what they are.

One of the things I installed actually worked, but after rebooting now I again have no notifications...

My question is
Is there a way I can see what I did install and how to remove all of the useless junk and start fresh (hopefully with notifications again) ?

applying : `less /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz | grep -B1 '^Install:'`

Apparently I have installed the following:

```
mail-notification-evolution 
screenlets screenlets-pack-all
```

I only mention the ones I think relevant or maybe conflicting and some of the installed aren't shown because I can't seem to be able to scroll up further.. any ideas of how to remover them ?

Comment: What exactly did you install?

Comment: thats the thing .. i have no clue .. just copy paste some command lines some guys recommended .. and i can't find the posts that i copied from. Idiotic, i know :(

Comment: Did you install addons to Thunderbird, or other programs?

Comment: the only addon i have is 'firetray'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thunderbird extensions you have installed are in

```
~/.thunderbird/123abc.default/extensions/
```

usually, with `123abc` being some random characters.

In that directory, there are extensions either as `*.xpi` files, or as subdirectories.
In both cases, they can have a clear name, or a cryptic number in `{}`.

I propose to list them in order of last change, and try to identify the ones that match the interesting time range:

```
$ cd ~/.thunderbird/*.default/extensions/
$ ls -ltr
```

The direcories contain a file `install.rdf` that should explain what it contains.

Maybe what you see is easy to identify, if not ask in a comment here.

---

From comments: So you see the directory `{9533f794-00b4-4354-aa15-c2bbda6989f8}`.

From asking google for `9533f794-00b4-4354-aa15-c2bbda6989f8`, it seems to be the addon `firetray`. With the relation to "tray", it is probably be related to the notifications.

Hard to tell whether it's the useful part of what you installed, or not.
Experiment if it's not clear to you too: Take a look at it's settings, disable or remove it.

---

If you need to find out which software packages you installed recently, independent of Thunderbird, like with `apt-get install foo`:
There are log files of the package system to help.

The files are in `/var/log/apt/`, named `history...`. The newest are `history.log` and `history.log.1.gz`

The ones with `.gz` are compressed but `less` should be able to show then anyway:

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log
less /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz
```

As you are interested mainly in new installs, try this (also with `history.log`):

```
less /var/log/apt/history.log.1.gz | grep -B1 '^Install:'
```

(If `less` should not be configured to unpack `*.gz` files, `zcat` works in a similar way.)

Comment: this is what got:
`total 4
drwxr-xr-x 6 ibrahim ibrahim 4096 Sep 24 19:07 {9533f794-00b4-4354-aa15-c2bbda6989f8}`
i dont understand what this says ! ofcourse ibrahim is my name

Comment: That means you have one addon, it seems to be called `firetray`. That is probably related to notifications - but I can not tell whether it's the good or the bad part. Take a look at it's settings, or uninstall?

Comment: seems that changing the settings of 'firetray' kindda got my notifications back (the mail icon turns blue) but i am still unable to get the ubuntu notification on the upper right corner and still not sound.

Comment: Ok, you did not say what kind of software you installed - normal packages too, outside of Thunderbird?

Comment: i remember using the terminal and some lines .. so i am assuming i installed from outside thunderbird.

Comment: I have added where to find the log of package changes

Comment: You can edit the question, that's easier to read.